# Let me edit my own deleted post

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, deleted-posts

This is admittedly a rare occurrence, but there are a couple instance where I have posted an answer, was beat out by a few seconds by another user who posted essentially the same answer, deleted my answer, and then realized I had something else to add that could still bring value to the question.

My choices now are either to write a new answer or undelete the old one edit it (or just walk away).  What I really want to do is just edit the deleted post directly, and then undelete when the edit is finished.

A few other times I'll realize I've mis-read the question and will immediately delete my post.  I'd like to edit the deleted post saying something like "Misread the question, nothing to see here" for other users with 10K rep (I think I've seen one or two of these from most of the frequent SO users), but the only way to do that now is to undelete it first.  Of course, I could just do things in the right order in the first place, but I don't always remember.

Comment: facepalm.  I could swear I've been unable to do this in the past.  At least I can mark my own request "completed".

Comment: Are you the only one with the power of the red tags?

Comment: Oops, it won't let me add the tag back on...sorry.

Comment: You mean like what happened 10 seconds ago?

Comment: Lol, it's okay.  Any of the mods have the power to apply red tags.  Though if any of us who aren't directly part of the SO team started marking everything 'status-accepted' or 'status-declined' unilaterally we'd likely have some explaining to do.

Comment: Hmm, looks like they made it so you cannot edit your deleted posts again :(

Comment: Thanks for the comment - removed the 'completed' mark based on that.

Comment: I can still edit other people's deleted posts on SO, but I don't know about <10k users.

Comment: Looks like it works again now. Not sure what happened back then. I will report and come back if it happens to me again. Thanks!

Comment: There is certainly a bug somewhere. Just happened to me again that it says that the post is deleted and you cannot edit it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *can* edit a deleted post. I've done it a few times. Here's [the edit list from one of my revised answers](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1129082/revisions) showing that I answered, deleted, edited, then undeleted.

> **Editor's note:** This ability was [later removed for self-deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296101/why-can-i-not-edit-a-self-deleted-question), because it was being abused by spammers.

Comment: It hasn't let me in the past - I'll try again next time.

Comment: Perhaps a 10K thing?  Though I've been 10K for a _long_ time now.

Comment: I have < 10K and can edit deleted posts

Comment: It must be newish, because I would get 404s when trying to edit a deleted post...

Comment: You cannot edit a [**self-deleted** question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178760/couple-of-issues-with-roomba-turbocharging/179555#179555).

Answer (score 3):

Happens to me from time to time too. You risk getting downvoted as a dupe while editing a live answer.

Comment: People that are downvoting similar answers are voting wrong imo.

Comment: @jinguy, I agree, however, there are a lot of simplish questions where you see VERY simple answers happening 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 15 minutes AND 20 minutes ago. It's kind of annoying to see so many people posting answers that are duplicates of things posted ten minutes prior.

Comment: I typically encourage authors of dupes to delete their post, and up-vote the original.

Comment: Well, while seeing a highly upvoted answer can show the communities confidence in an answer, so can seeing 5 copies of the same answer.

Comment: @jjnguy, which is OK in short time periods, but it is very annoying when people are posting almost identical answers to things that have been posted 10 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I can edit every entry in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248296/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow-closed) on StackOverflow.  Go try it!

You have to have 10K rep to view the deleted entries I am speaking of.

Comment: Hm, perhaps this should be considered a bug?