# Show my posts deleted by me on my Activity page

Tags: feature-request, edits, posting, activity-dropdown

It is [possible to edit my own deleted post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6347/let-me-edit-my-own-deleted-post). [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
However, it is [not possible to know what posts of mine I deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The combination of the two seems silly.

I can delete my answer because it strikes me it's wrong, do some research, edit and undelete. I've done that, it works.
But if in the meanwhile I close the browser window or get distracted, I might not even find my self-deleted answer to edit and undelete. Because it won't show up on the list of my actions.

Please:

- Allow seeing your own post deleted by **you** (and not by something else) on the Activity tab
- Introduce `deleted` action on that list to know **you** deleted your post.