# Does anybody, ever, get un-question-banned?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

As with every other kind of problem imaginable, people frequently come into the Lounge to discuss the problem of being question banned (and how we, personally, could of course help them with this).

But unlike the other problems, I basically never hear about anybody who successfully reversed the ban, even though many of the users did indeed try after understanding what happened. Especially confusing for them is that they tried to "clean up their act" by deleting bad questions.

All I'm saying is, a lot of people seem to have trouble with the question banning mechanism, and I've never heard of anybody being un-question-banned. Does this *ever* actually happen? I feel that some users are left question-banned unnecessarily. And secondly, I feel that question bans are currently handed out too lightly- although, of course, it's difficult to judge since it's impossible to find the offending material for any given user, even if you're a 10k repper who can see the questions they deleted.

Specifically, the latest user can't even *see* his own deleted questions. How the hell is he supposed to fix up his questions if he can't even *view* them?

Comment: Haven't heard of any success stories either.  I suppose it depends on how close to the edge you are (those who barely cross the threshold probably move on with their lives as opposed to those who are way deep into the algorithm).

Comment: I remember a user here on Meta mentioned (in the process of answering a question) about being banned for a while. I don't know whether it is appropriate to name them.

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: There has been only one case in the C++ lounge that I'm aware of. And that's because a couple of us went and serially upvoted the person's posts.

Comment: i was banned for question  on meta and lifted up successfully ... its like i banned at 140 rep and lifted up at something like 1500rep

Comment: @Shog9 It'd be nice if you could give us some statistics (if those can be disclosed)

Comment: I have seen a number of members reverse the ban after some undeletions, edits and upvotes. The kicker: question banned folks are already behind the 8-ball on quality, as evidenced by them being question banned in the first place.

Comment: @Asad: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172300/what-happens-to-folks-who-get-question-banned-by-and-large/172773#172773 (disclaimer: numbers might all be wrong)

Comment: FWIW: if you think someone shouldn't be banned, up-vote something good they've done. It's really that simple.