# Is there a way to safely sock puppet a banned account?

Tags: support, sock-puppets

I'd like to look into the user experience of being question/answer banned for a bit, but I'd like to do so without jeopardizing the standing of my main account. Knitting some socks for this is risky, though, as the account will inevitably be associated with my main account.

Is there a way to do this safely? And, is this something Stack Exchange would even be okay with?

Comment: Behind a proxy? Use Tor?! (New acc)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you looking to test?  Are you looking to see how hard/easy it is to get unbanned?

Comment: @psub Yes, but this is more a matter of the general user experience, and that is a subset of it.

Comment: @Emracool you realize that it probably would be far easier for you to get unbanned since you are already capable of writing a good question.... but I've often wondered the same as well, just not enough to be willing to get banned intentionally, so good luck.

Comment: Is there anything you'd like to know that is not already covered by this question and the answer by Shog? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172300/what-happens-to-folks-who-get-question-banned-by-and-large

Comment: @Bart Eh, it's interesting, but it doesn't actually speak to the complete user experience. Thanks, though!

Comment: @psub That is true, 'twould probably be easier for me. But the degree of actual contribution is about the same, so I'd at least get an idea for that. Plus, that's not all there is in UX, so I still think it would be interesting.

Comment: I wonder how much of a user experience you're going to get though @Emracool. You'd have to actively post bad content. I.e. you're not stumbling into anything. And getting out of it would be more trivial for you since you're already aware of what's good and what's bad.

Comment: @Bart I think there would be more to be learned than you think, but I cannot really disagree with you, since, as I haven't been banned, I can't speak to the process

Comment: I've been banned on MSO a couple of times. What do you want to know?

Comment: @GUI The only question I have currently is: is it possible to the type a question in even when you're banned? So that you go to submit, only to find out you can't. That's all I know to ask without actually experiencing it.

Comment: No, if I recall correctly, you are redirected to a html page stating you're banned when you click on 'Ask Question'

Comment: From a user experience point of view, it's a nightmare, as the html is a text of a link... not even clickable.

Comment: @GUI Hmm, thanks... I'm curious, how long ago was your ban? If you don't mind me asking details, of course.

Comment: Not at all, I was banned in June 2011, rescued by Jeff, banned again, rescued again, banned again... for making user experience proposals. Basically.

Comment: The third time I was banned, I just let time pass. Haven't been banned after that.

Comment: @GUI Mind going to chat later today?

Comment: Sure. I have a lousy connection, but we can try. What time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You risk having the banned accounts deleted, merged into your main account, or suspended. You risk having your main account suspended or merged into a sockpuppet account. You risk triggering automatic blocks or rate-limits on any of your accounts or IPs or other accounts that share those IPs.

Not saying any of this *will* happen, but... Be aware of the risks. If you're intentionally planning on doing the sorts of things that might get an account banned, there's a somewhat higher chance of this ending badly than for a normal "just testing" sockpuppet...

#### See also:

- [I am a sockpuppet, may I exist if I have a real purpose?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/i-am-a-sockpuppet-may-i-exist-if-i-have-a-real-purpose)
- [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: Not saying we _will_ shoot you if you cross this fence just saying we _might_. It's a _possibility_ ;)

Comment: You do know you can get around the auto IP ban with Tor.

Comment: You do know you can ban Tor IPs too. @Cole

Comment: @Shog9 "get new identity"

Comment: The problem with anonymity isn't that it isn't possible; it's that you have to be *really committed to getting it*. @Cole. I'm not gonna tell people, "Do X and you're safe from Y" when X implies a lot of work they may not be willing to go through and Y is something I'd rather folks weren't doing anyway. If you feel like you have to *ask permission* to do something, you *may* not be well-equipped to accomplish it successfully without that permission...

Comment: @Shog9 fair enough

Comment: I mean, I could do it that way, @Cole, I just wondered if there was a better/safer way. I tend not to follow "better to ask forgiveness than permission" whenever reasonable.

Comment: So the short answer is "no".